# Audio Recording is not working during Screen-share with Zoom or other app

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to record voice with `AVAudioRecorder`. It is working fine if Screen-share is not enable. But notice when i share my device screen with Zoom or any other app. `AVAudioSession` is not active.

Here i attach code that i added for audio record

```
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do{
            try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord,options: .defaultToSpeaker)
            try session.setActive(true)
            
            let settings = [
                AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
            ]
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: getFileUrl(), settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
            audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
            self.nextBtn.isHidden = true
        }catch let error {
            print("Error \(error)")
        }
```

When i hit record button it shows me error `NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561017449 "Session activation failed"`.

Here i attach video.

https://share.icloud.com/photos/0a09o5DCNip6Rx_GnTpht7K3A

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to comment or I would. (Almost there lol!) Have you tried `AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.overridemutedmicrophoneinterrupt`?

**Edit**
The more I looked into this it seems like if Zoom is using the hardware then the iPhone won't be able to record that stream. I think that's the idea behind the `AVAudioSession.sharedSession()` being a singleton.

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/3727255-overridemutedmicrophoneinterrupt):

> **Type Property**
>
> `overrideMutedMicrophoneInterruption`: An option that indicates
> whether the system interrupts the audio session when it mutes the
> built-in microphone.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> ```swift
> AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions { get }
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Some devices include a privacy feature that mutes the built-in
> microphone at the hardware level in certain conditions, such as when
> you close the Smart Folio cover of an iPad. When this occurs, the
> system interrupts the audio session that’s capturing input from the
> microphone. Attempting to start audio input after the system mutes the
> microphone results in an error.   If your app uses an audio session
> category that supports input and output, such as playAndRecord, you
> can set this option to disable the default behavior and continue using
> the session. Disabling the default behavior may be useful to allow
> your app to continue playback when recording or monitoring a muted
> microphone doesn’t lead to a poor user experience. When you set this
> option, playback continues as normal, and the microphone hardware
> produces sample buffers, but with values of 0.
> **Important**
>
> Attempting to use this option with a session category that doesn’t
> support audio input results in an error.